# multiply two numbers by a decimal

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a program that multiplies a dog's weight by the number of days boarded by the rate of $0.50 a pound. I can't figure out how to incorporate the rate in with the weight and number of days. Help please! This is what I have so far and it is homework. I know the rate is missing, but I don't know where to inject it in this program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dogWeight, boardDays;
        Console.Write("Enter dog's weight ");
        dogWeight = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter number of days  ");
        boardDays = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Total amount is $ ");
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: Just add another variable of `0.5`. Convert the strings to decimals or doubles, and do your math.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably get much more benefit out of this homework if you discuss your questions with your teacher. They know a lot more about what they thought they taught you, and what concepts in particular they are trying to have you learn, and so can provide much better advice.

That said, from the code you posted, there are a couple of different things you are missing:

1. You allow the user to enter information as a `string` type, but the computer won't be able to do math with that. You will need to convert to some suitable numeric type; for this specific type of calculation, where monetary values are involved, the `decimal` type is most appropriate. Conversion can be done a variety of ways, but the simplest is to use the `decimal.Parse()` method.
2. You need to incorporate the per-pound rate. This involves not just knowing the rate itself, but also using it in an appropriate calculation. Since the rate is constant, rather than being entered by the user, you can use the `const` keyword in your program when declaring a variable assigned to that value.

Rather than write your whole homework assignment out for you, here are a couple of sample pieces of code that illustrate the above:

```
// This will convert from the string the user entered to a decimal
// value you can use in a calculation. Do something similar for boardDays
// as well.

decimal dogWeightNumber = decimal.Parse(dogWeight);
```

```
// This will declare a constant of the correct type and value. Note the M
// at the end of the literal. This is what C# uses to indicate that the
// literal value should have the decimal type instead of double (the default)
const decimal perPoundRate = 0.5M;

// Then you can put all of the values together in a single total cost:

decimal total = dogWeightNumber * perPoundRate * boardDaysNumber;
```

The rate is "dollars per pound per day", so multiplying it by the weight (pounds) and the duration of the stay (days) gets rid of the pounds and days units, leaving you just with dollars, which is the result you want.

Hopefully, you can put all of that together in your program to finish the homework assignment. If not, I do *strongly* encourage you to meet with your teacher to get additional help. It's their job to help you learn, and they are in the position to provide you the best help given the coursework.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood the problem well, then this you should be doing:

```
double c= (double)dogWeight*boardDays;
double rate = c*(0.50);
Console.write(rate);
```

Keeping in mind that dogWeight can be in decimal values, and board days in integer, we should typecast their product in to double so as to be precise.

I hope i clear your doubt!

Comment: _Especially_ since this is homework, an answer is not really helpful to the OP unless you explain _precisely_ why it's the correct answer. Just showing code isn't going to help them learn. Also, when providing code to people new to the art, you should try extra hard to make sure the code you post can actually compile. It's hard for a beginner to know the difference between a simple typo and some concept they just don't understand.